# Distributing 12 books to 3 children.

Tags: permutations, combinations

The number of ways of distributing six identical maths books and six identical physics books among three students gets at least one maths and at least one physics book is?

My attempt: 
So I have learnt to distribute objects using the multinomial technique which states that when you have $n$ different objects and $r$ different groups (when no group is empty) is :$ r^n - rC1 (r-1)^n ..... (-1)^{r-1} rCr-1$
But the problem arising here is that those books are not all different but 6 each are identical.
The problem with my application is arising because I have just taught to apply a formula on a basic type of question.
The answer can have a method different from the multinomial one. And also how do we assess these kind of problems?

Comment: Have you been taught anything about distributing identical objects to distinct boxes ?

Comment: Yes using the multinomial technique , I have been.

Comment: But here , there are two sets of identical objects , how would we resolve that

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between distributing distinct objects to distinct boxes, and (here) distributing identical objects to distinct boxes.

For this, you can use [Theorem 1 of stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29),

e.g. for the 6 identical maths books to 3 (obviously distinct) children, $\binom52$ ways

Do a similar computation for the physics books, and multiply.

Comment: Could you explain why it's not $5\choose2$?

Comment: Sorry, typo corrected

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Distribute first one math book to each kid. Then you can distribute the remaining 3 books any way you want. How many ways can you do this? (if not sure, you have 3 situations: one kid gets all 3, one kid gets 2, and everyone gets one. How many possibilities are in each situation)?

Do the same for physics books.